# How to get the latest x entries of a table in Lua?

Tags: lua

If I have *(for example)* a table with 300 entries, how would I get the latest x entries only?
I was thinking of doing the next, but I'm wondering if there is a better/more optimized way to do this exact thing.

```
local TestTable = {}

-- Populate table
for i = 1, 300, 1 do
    print('Adding: ' .. i)
    table.insert(TestTable , i)
end

-- Get latest x of table
function GetLatestFromTable(OriginalTable, Amount)
    local TableLength = #OriginalTable
    local Retval = {}

    for i = 1, Amount, 1 do
        if TableLength - i <= 0 then break end -- Dont allow to go under 0

        table.insert(Retval, OriginalTable[TableLength - i])

        print("Adding to Retval: " .. OriginalTable[TableLength - i] .. ' (Index: ' .. TableLength - i .. ')')
    end

    return Retval
end


print(#TestTable)
local LatestTable = GetLatestFromTable(TestTable, 10)
print(#LatestTable)
```

Comment: You can move the inner if into the loop, e.g. `for i = math.max(1, #OriginalTable - Amount + 1), #OriginalTable do`. If you want to avoid copying altogether you can use metatables to simulate a slice, but that seems overkill.

Comment: Alright, I'm going ahead and try it out, thanks!

Comment: Do the items need to be in reverse order, or can they be in the same order as in the original array?

Comment: Try `LatestTable = {table.unpack(TestTable,#TestTable-100+1)}`.

Comment: Note that lhfs solution does not work for very long tables, `table.unpack` has a limit

Comment: Oh and if you only want to iterate over the sub-array, you could make a custom iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Luke100000, one way could be to use `Lua` custom iterators. In `Lua`, an iterator is a special function which, when called, will return the next value. It is made possible by the fact that functions are *first-class citizen* in `Lua` and they can refer to previous scope with a mecanism named [`closure`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-closures-in-lua-programming#:%7E:text=In%20Lua%2C%20any%20function%20is%20a%20closure.%20In,be%20both%20keys%20and%20values%20in%20Lua%20tables.).

To answer the question, one could start implement a general iterator over a given range.

```
function IterateRange (Table, Min, Max)
  
  local ClosureIndex = Min - 1
  local ClosureMax   = math.min(Max, #Table)
  
  local function Closure ()
    if (ClosureIndex < ClosureMax) then
      ClosureIndex = ClosureIndex + 1
      return Table[ClosureIndex]
    end
  end

  return Closure
end
```

`IterateRange` is a function returning an `anonymous function`. The anonymous function does not take any parameter. It simply update the `ClosureIndex` index defined in the local scope of `IterateRange` and return the table value.

The first thing that the anonymous function do is to increment `ClosureIndex`. For that reason, `ClosureIndex` must be initialized to `Min - 1`.

This function works as one might expect:

```
TestTable = {}

for i = 1, 300, 1 do
    print('Adding: ' .. i)
    table.insert(TestTable , i)
end

for Value in IterateRange(TestTable, 290, 300) do
  print(Value)
end

290
291
292
293
294
295
296
297
298
299
300
```

Now, it's trivial to reuse this general iterator to iterate over the *last N entries* of a given table:

```
function IterateLastEntries (Table, Count)
  local TableSize  = #Table
  local StartIndex = (TableSize - Count)
  return IterateRange(Table, StartIndex, TableSize)
end
```

It also work as one might expect:

```
TestTable = {}

for i = 1, 300, 1 do
    print('Adding: ' .. i)
    table.insert(TestTable , i)
end

for Value in IterateLastEntries(TestTable, 10) do
  print(Value)
end

290
291
292
293
294
295
296
297
298
299
300
```

And finally, to summarize all this in a fully copy & pasteable solution:

```
TestTable = {}

for i = 1, 300, 1 do
    print('Adding: ' .. i)
    table.insert(TestTable , i)
end

function IterateRange (Table, Min, Max)
  
  local ClosureIndex = Min - 1
  local ClosureMax   = math.min(Max, #Table)
  
  local function Closure ()
    if (ClosureIndex < ClosureMax) then
      ClosureIndex = ClosureIndex + 1
      return Table[ClosureIndex]
    end
  end

  return Closure
end

function IterateLastEntries (Table, Count)
  local TableSize  = #Table
  local StartIndex = (TableSize - Count)
  return IterateRange(Table, StartIndex, TableSize)
end

for Value in IterateLastEntries(TestTable, 10) do
  print(Value)
end
```

This should return:

```
290
291
292
293
294
295
296
297
298
299
300
```

I will let the OP update the code in order to achieve the same results for `30` entries.

Comment: Edit: I fixed 2 issues in the function `IterateRange`, we want to use `math.min` and not `math.max`. We also need to compare `ClosureIndex` instead of `Max`.

Answer (score 1):

For keys in sequence (and values are string/number) a call to `table.concat()` allows range parameter.

```
local tab = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"}

print(table.concat(tab, '\n', #tab - 1, #tab)) -- Last two entries
```

See: [table.concat()](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.concat)